# How to fix the absence of scrolling in Editor inside of ScrollView in MAUI?

Tags: maui

Editor placed inside StackLayout that is inside ScrollView is not scrolling in Android. (can't check iOS)

Tried setting scrollview ScrollOrientation to Neither but it didn't help.

Here is the sample code:

```
public class TestingPage : ContentPage
    {
        public TestingPage()
        {
            var box = new BoxView
            {
                HeightRequest = 80,
                BackgroundColor = Colors.Gray
            };
            var editor = new Editor
            {
                Text = "defaul \n qweqweqweq \n 123123 \n 123123\n 123123\n 123123\n 123123\n 123123\n 123123\n 123123\n 123123\n 123123",
                TextColor = Colors.Red,
                HeightRequest = 80,
            };
            var box2 = new BoxView
            {
                HeightRequest = 80,
                BackgroundColor = Colors.Gray
            };

            var stack = new StackLayout
            {
                Children =
                {
                    box, editor, box2
                }
            };

            var scroll = new ScrollView
            {
                Content = stack,
                Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical,
            };

            Content = scroll;
        }
    }
```

Does anyone has workarounds or maybe I'm doing something wrong, because it looks like a thing that must work.

P.S. The problem is that **text editor** is not scrolling. Editor's height is 80 and there are >10 lines of text so you can't see all lines. And also you can't scroll those lines. I want to be able to scroll text inside TextEditor.

Here is the [video](https://Left%20one%20is%20the%20same%20code%20but%20Content%20=%20stack;%20and%20editor%20scrolls%20there.).
Right emulator is the code from above.
Left one is the same code but Content = stack; and editor scrolls there.

Comment: Can you please clarify and provide a screenshot of the problem? Does the scrollbar of the Editor control show up at all?

Answer (score 1):

> Editor placed inside StackLayout that is inside ScrollView is not
> scrolling in Android.

Your code is right. It did not work because the elements you write do not have enough hight to fill the `ScrollView`.

You can try to set the hight higher like the code below and the ScrollView will work well.

```cs
var box = new BoxView {
  HeightRequest = 800,
  BackgroundColor = Colors.Gray
};

var editor = new Editor {
  Text = "defaul \n qweqweqweq \n 123123 \n 123123\n 123123\n 123123\n 123123\n 123123\n 123123\n 123123\n 123123\n 123123",
  TextColor = Colors.Red,
  HeightRequest = 800,
};

var box2 = new BoxView {
  HeightRequest = 800,
  BackgroundColor = Colors.Gray
};
```

Comment: I guess I didn't explain the problem clearly enough. The problem is text editor is not scrolling. Editor's height is 80 and there are >10 lines of text so you can't see all lines. And also you can't scroll those lines. I want to be able to scroll text inside TextEditor.

Comment: The ScrollView can not make the text scroll and the editor doesn't have a method to make the editor scroll on Android. You can check the [Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/editor) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView is throwing you off here. Its irrelevant to make an Editor scrollable. ScrollView is more for long paragraphs of text, not a container for other layouts.

For example these both allow scrolling in the editor:

```
var editor = new Editor
{
    Text = "defaul \n qweqweqweq \n 123123 \n 123123\n 123123\n 123123\n 123123\n 123123\n 123123\n 123123\n 123123\n 123123",
    TextColor = Colors.Red,
    HeightRequest = 80,
};

// Will scroll
Content = editor;

// Another option
Content = new StackLayout { Children = { editor } };
```

(Btw MAUI has an issue with Editors not scrolling on iOS but this should fix your Android issue. Still waiting on a fix in .NET 7 as of Sept '23) https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12485

Answer (score -1):

Add this code inside the scroll

```
VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
```

Comment: `FillAndExpand`, just like all other `*AndExpand` options, is deprecated in .NET MAUI and will be removed in a future release. It should not be used anymore. Also, even in Xamarin.Forms you should never use `FillAndExpand` inside a ScrollView, because that would be unrestrained.