# Scroll in editor Net Maui Mac catalyst

Tags: scroll, editor, maui

I've been trying for hours but without results to make the scroll of an editor work in my net maui project.

```
<Frame>
x:Name="F_MessaggioDaInviare"
Grid.Column="0"
Margin="0,0,0,0"
Padding="5"
BackgroundColor="LightGreen"
BorderColor="#3CB371"
CornerRadius="5"
HasShadow="False"
VerticalOptions="Fill">

    <Editor
    AutoSize="Disabled"
    MaxLength="1000"
    x:Name="E_MessaggioDaInviare"
    Margin="5,0,0,0"
    BackgroundColor="#3CB371"
    TextColor="LightGreen"
    FontSize="14"
    IsTextPredictionEnabled="False"
    FontAutoScalingEnabled="False"
    TextChanged="E_MessaggioDaInviare_TextChanged"
    />
</Frame>
```

Here I only found this:
[How to fix the absence of scrolling in Editor inside of ScrollView in MAUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76417728/how-to-fix-the-absence-of-scrolling-in-editor-inside-of-scrollview-in-maui)
Scrollview is a good idea but i'm not able to scroll in you bottom of editor automatically.

I also thought about enlarging vertically the editor when the text wraps. but if you don't hit enter it's all on one line (newline depends on the width of the editor).

I try to set "HeightRequest", nothing; I tested, the height of the editor in pixels remains the same even if there are 20 lines of text inside.

Thank you so much!

Comment: There  is a known issue on GitHub: [Editors not scrollable on iOS/Catalyst](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12485).

Comment: Thank you for replay!

Yes, I had seen that page by googling. So we have to wait for November. Are there no alternatives? The idea of scrolling down the scroll bar is not contemplated at the code level? Can it be done? 

I tried to use "ScrollToAsync" but without good results. I will try with "autosize".

Comment: I can reproduce and wrapping the editor in a Scrollview cannot solve this question. But it shows that in .NET8 preview it has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue on GitHub: [Editors not scrollable on iOS/Catalyst #12485](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12485).

From the comment, we can see that this issue has been fixed in .NET8. I have tested with the latest .NET8 Preview7 and this issue has been fixed now.

And .NET8 preview is supported in VS for mac 2022 now. If you want to have a try, you could refer to [Announcing .NET MAUI in .NET 8 Preview 7: Keyboard Accelerators](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-dotnet-maui-in-dotnet-8-preview-7/#how-to-update).

Hope it helps!